# Solution for runtime price calc for price sorting problem

Tags: elasticsearch, nuxt.js, elastic-stack, nuxtjs3

We have nuxtjs framework for our frontend and build a API with Elasticsearch for searching hotels/accommodations.

We have a two call api when user search. First call is availabilty and second call is price. The price we fetch is based on nightprice.  Then on client calculation on runtime for total price.

2 night searched = 2 * night_price = total_price

This works ok, but we cannot add sorting on total_price value because its runtime value.

Ideas to solve this issue?

Our idea is store ALL possible combination a user can be searching for and this store in ES. But those are 100+ mil documents.

remco

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [Runtime Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) . The benefits are :

- saving storage costs and increasing ingestion speed
- immediately use it in search requests, aggregations, filtering, and sorting.
- doesn’t increase the index size

So, you can define a field during search :

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "total_price": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['night_price'].value * params['multiplier'])"
      },
      "params": {
        "multiplier": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total_price": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

While sending the query, you need to set the value of the multiplier parameter.